# Overriding a core data setter: warning: 'MyClass' may not respond to '-setPrimitiveName:newName:'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm overriding a Core Data setter with this code:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:newName];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

It works perfectly, however I'm getting the a compiler warning:

```
warning: 'MyClass' may not respond to '-setPrimitiveName:newName:'
```

Is this correct? If so, can I suppress this warning ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it. The `setPrimitiveName:` method will be generated automatically by Core Data. To get rid of the warning, add a category interface at the top of your implementation file which declares primitive accessors.

```
// MyClass.m
@interface MyClass (CoreDataPrimitiveAccessors)

- (void)setPrimitiveName:(NSString *)newName;
- (NSString *)primitiveName;

@end

// class implementation goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler warnings suck: `[self setPrimitiveValue:newName forKey:@"name"];`

Comment: Apple says the "setPrimitiveName:" is better to use

Comment: `setPrimitiveName:` is no longer defined in Core Data

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the method in the header (MyClass.h)

```
- (void)setPrimitiveName:(NSString *)newName;
```

Comment: Ya, I've added it. But now it is complaining about the method definition not found!